# How can I limit the threads quantity used by a spring state machine instance?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-statemachine

I have an event queue with n message listeners. When a message arrives, one message listener takes it, gets a state machine instance from the corresponding pool, sets the state machine context and starts it.
This works perfect but I have an issue with threading. Since state machine instances are limited by its pool size, I thought total threads quantity would have a limit, but I'm wrong:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'consume' threw exception
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:395) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:298) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:848) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:771) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:102) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:198) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1311) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:752) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1254) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1224) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:102) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1470) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) [na:1.8.0_152]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957) [na:1.8.0_152]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1603) [na:1.8.0_152]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:334) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService.schedule(Executors.java:729) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskScheduler.schedule(ConcurrentTaskScheduler.java:182) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.state.AbstractState.scheduleAction(AbstractState.java:415) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.state.AbstractState.scheduleStateActions(AbstractState.java:377) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.state.AbstractState.entry(AbstractState.java:208) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.state.ObjectState.entry(ObjectState.java:156) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.entryToState(AbstractStateMachine.java:1216) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.entryToState(AbstractStateMachine.java:1161) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.setCurrentStateInternal(AbstractStateMachine.java:971) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.setCurrentState(AbstractStateMachine.java:949) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.switchToState(AbstractStateMachine.java:841) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.access$400(AbstractStateMachine.java:77) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine$2.transit(AbstractStateMachine.java:301) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.handleTriggerTrans(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:248) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.processTriggerQueue(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:395) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.access$100(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:61) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor$1.run(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:281) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.scheduleEventQueueProcessing(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:300) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.execute(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:144) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.sendEventInternal(AbstractStateMachine.java:559) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.sendEvent(AbstractStateMachine.java:211) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.sendEvent(AbstractStateMachine.java:223) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at io.botbit.backend.consumers.EventConsumer.consume(EventConsumer.java:39) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
... 14 common frames omitted
```

Analyzing the stack trace, the cause is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

How can I limit the threads quantity used by a spring state machine instance?

Thanks in advance!

## Update 1

I did what @SpaceTrucker suggests:

```
@Bean(name = "stateMachineTaskScheduler")
public ConcurrentTaskScheduler stateMachineTaskScheduler() {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
    ConcurrentTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(threadPool);
    return taskScheduler;
}
```

and then

`builder.configureConfiguration().withConfiguration().taskScheduler(stateMachineTaskScheduler());`

Now state machines are using this pool. The problem is that all state machine instances are using the same instance of this pool instead each state machine instance having it's own taskScheduler instance.

Comment: But if every state machine would use its own scheduler, wouldn't you end up with the same problem you are trying to solve - too many threads?

Comment: State machine instances are limited, because they are pooled. If each machine has a task scheduler that has a limited threadPool, then I assume the total # of threads is limited because no one would be creating threads on demand. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-config-commonsettings) provide this example configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
public class Config17
        extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config)
            throws Exception {
        config
            .withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(true)
                .beanFactory(new StaticListableBeanFactory())
                .taskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor())
                .taskScheduler(new ConcurrentTaskScheduler())
                .listener(new StateMachineListenerAdapter<States, Events>());
    }
}
```

You just need to replace the `taskScheduler` with a bean that is configured for your needs. For example another instance of [`ConcurrentTaskScheduler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ConcurrentTaskScheduler.html) that uses a `scheduledExecutor` with a limited number of threads.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I did what you suggested, see #Update 1 in the original post please.